# Serilog.Sinks.EventLog - Event Id

Tags: .net-core, service-worker, serilog, event-viewer

I am using Serilog.Sinks.EventLog for logging to event viewer and Serilog.Sinks.File for logging to file.
Both are working as expected,only problem is when i log to event viewer it is taking random Event ID, is there any way to pass Event ID.I searched a lot and not found any solution.
My requirement is for eg. when the worker service is started Event ID X should be logged, when some error occurred then Event ID Y should be logged.
My appsettings.json configurations is as follows:

```
{
    "Name": "EventLog",
    "Args": {
      "manageEventSource": false,
      "source": "CTS",
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to define custom `EventID`s, you'll have to implement your own [`IEventIdProvider`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/IEventIdProvider.cs#L22) and then [tell the sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/LoggerConfigurationEventLogExtensions.cs#L108) to use your provider instead of the [default one](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.EventLog/Sinks/EventLog/EventIdHashProvider.cs#L23).

```
.WriteTo(..., eventIdProvider: yourProvider)
```

---

```
public static LoggerConfiguration EventLog(
    this LoggerSinkConfiguration loggerConfiguration,
    string source,
    string logName = null,
    string machineName = ".",
    bool manageEventSource = false,
    string outputTemplate = DefaultOutputTemplate,
    IFormatProvider formatProvider = null,
    LogEventLevel restrictedToMinimumLevel = LevelAlias.Minimum,
    IEventIdProvider eventIdProvider = null) // <#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#<#
{
    // ...
}
```

---

The source code of the sink is on GitHub and it's fairly easy to understand how it works: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-eventlog